# Only want to initialize the second function if the first one is satisfied the statement

Tags: anchor, rust

Hi I am building a program where I have two functions that initialize only if the first statement is approved by the macro's require_gt, I want the second function to initialize else I want it to fail.
If the dogfunc has a value greater than 0 don't initialize the CatIni else Initialize.

```
// This is your program's public key and it will update
// automatically when you build the project.
declare_id!("DVRSmsVnyTNNZS21AGpT1thPD71LUz5C18uvY9b5bFwn");

#[program]
mod hello_anchor {
    use super::*;
    pub fn doginiti(ctx: Context<DOGINI>,data:u8) -> Result<()> { 
        let dognumber =&mut ctx.accounts.dog;
        dognumber.dog = data;
        msg!("value of dog number is {}",dognumber.dog);
        Ok(())
    }
    
    require_gt!(doginiti(), 0);
    pub fn cat(ctx:Context<CATINI>,data:u8,color:String) -> Result<()> {
            let catnumberandcolor  =&mut ctx.accounts.cat;
            catnumberandcolor.cat = data;
            catnumberandcolor.color = color;
            Ok(())
        }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct DOGINI<'info> {
    // We must specify the space in order to initialize an account.
    // First 8 bytes are default account discriminator,
    // next 8 bytes come from NewAccount.data being type u64.
    // (u64 = 64 bits unsigned integer = 8 bytes)
    #[account(init, payer = signer, space = 8 + 32)]
    pub dog: Account<'info, DogAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}


#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CATINI<'info> {
    // We must specify the space in order to initialize an account.
    // First 8 bytes are default account discriminator,
    // next 8 bytes come from NewAccount.data being type u64.
    // (u64 = 64 bits unsigned integer = 8 bytes)
    #[account(init, payer = signer, space = 8 + 32)]
    pub cat: Account<'info, CatAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct DogAccount {
       dog:u8
}

#[account]
pub struct CatAccount{
    cat:u8,
    color:String,
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want them to be dependent on each other, you'll need to include both of them in the same instruction, meaning:

```
#[program]
mod hello_anchor {
    use super::*;
    pub fn init_all(ctx: Context<InitAll>, dog_data: u8, cat_data: u8, color: String) -> Result<()> { 
        let dognumber = &mut ctx.accounts.dog;
        dognumber.dog = dog_data;
        msg!("value of dog number is {}",dognumber.dog);
        require_gt!(dognumber.dog, 0);
            
        let catnumberandcolor = &mut ctx.accounts.cat;
        catnumberandcolor.cat = cat_data;
        catnumberandcolor.color = ccolor;
        Ok(())
    }
}
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitAll<'info> {
    // We must specify the space in order to initialize an account.
    // First 8 bytes are default account discriminator,
    // next 8 bytes come from NewAccount.data being type u64.
    // (u64 = 64 bits unsigned integer = 8 bytes)
    #[account(init, payer = signer, space = 8 + 32)]
    pub dog: Account<'info, DogAccount>,
    #[account(init, payer = signer, space = 8 + 32)]
    pub cat: Account<'info, CatAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

Comment: Ha, I see , Makes more sense. It will have the same signer and the system program will create the account. But yet will be Initialize separately